# Can not call method that takes parameter in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

i have the following 2 classes:

```
public class PublishedExamsVO{

private HarfDate to;

public HarfDate getHarfTo() {
        return to;

      }
```

}

```
public class HarfDate {

public void setUserZone(String userZone) {}


}
```

and in my JSP i did the following to call the `setUserZone` method inside class HarfDate

```
${exam.getHarfTo().setUserZone(${userZone_)}
```

given that `exam` is an id inside display that's of type `PublishedExamsVO` and  `userZone_` 
is an attribute in my pageContext scope and `setUserZone` is not a setter method for any property inside the class its a normal method

the problem is that i'm unable to call these setter method by this way as the following exception is raised:

```
 javax.el.ELException: JBWEB006007:Failed to parse the expression [${exam.getHarfTo().setUserZone(${userZone_)}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't embed an EL expression (`${...}`) inside another one. It's useless. Just use

```
${exam.getHarfTo().setUserZone(userZone_)}
```